Run prod and pre prod in same vps docker.setup
I have web application which has pre prod and prod environments.
Due to cost I want to setup both pre prod and prod in same vps.
I have pre prod docker setup as below
Container.   Port
 pre-prod-db   5432 
  app.         8081
   UI.         9081
  Proxy.       80 443

But as per docker I can't have same port assigned to another container in prod setup. is there a way to have both pord and pre-prod setup done on same vps. In nginx reverse proxy; port need to be 80 & 443 which results in port conflict.

So just assign different port numbers. Better yet, assign them dynamically. Moreover, does nginx requires testing? Run a single nginx.

sorry for late reply, i cant configure nginx to have both production and pre_prod servers. which seems weird and i want production need to be completely isolated from pre_prod though running on same host. is docker network does any trick on this?
